# JavaScript compare hex string from buffer to Python

Tags: javascript, node.js, msgpack

I want to print a hex escaped sequence string from a `Buffer`.

for instance:

```
buffer = .... // => <Buffer d3 e9 52 18 4c e7 77 f7 d7>
```

if I do:

```
console.log(buffer.toString('hex'));
```

I get:

```
d3e952184ce777f7d7
```

but I want this representation with the `\x` representations (I get get from python and need to compare)

```
\xd3\xe9R\x18L\xe7w\xf7\xd7` // same as <Buffer d3 e9 52 18 4c e7 77 f7 d7>
```

Comment: What's up with the extra characters in the Python sample (e.g. R, L, w)? Can you add how that desired output is being generated? That's bigger than a python MAX_INT for example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
function encodehex (val) {
  if ((32 <= val) && (val <= 126))
    return String.fromCharCode(val);
  else
    return "\\x"+val.toString(16);
}

let buffer = [0xd3, 0xe9, 0x52, 0x18, 0x4c, 0xe7, 0x77, 0xf7, 0xd7];
console.log(buffer.map(encodehex).join(''));
```

You basically want to differentiate between printable and non-printable ASCII characters in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the buffer to array and each item to hex string by the map method. Finally join the array to string with `\x` (incl. leading '\x')

dirty example

```
let str = '\\x' +
  [0xd3, 0xe9, 0x52, 0x18, 0x4c, 0xe7, 0x77, 0xf7, 0xd7]
    .map(item => item.toString(16))
    .join('\\x');

console.log(str); // \xd3\xe9\x52\x18\x4c\xe7\x77\xf7\xd7
```

Alternatively you can split your toString('hex') string into two character chunks (array) and join it with `\\x` (incl. leading `\\x` as above) Like:

```
let str = 'd3e952184ce777f7d7';
str = '\\x' + str.match(/.{1,2}/g).join('\\x');
console.log(str); // \xd3\xe9\x52\x18\x4c\xe7\x77\xf7\xd7
```

Comment: Note that doesn't match the supplied desired output.

Comment: I ignored the weird letters (R, L, w, ...) ^^